# Does Linq and projects like i4o make object oriented DBs a viable alternateive to relational DBs?

Tags: linq, object, rdbms, object-oriented-database

Given Linq and technologies like [i4o](http://www.codeplex.com/i4o) is there any real reason why an object oriented database management system won't be a viable alternative to a relational database management system for new projects starting in the next 3 to 5 years?

Answer (score 2):

I would say "has been a viable alternative for the last 3 to 5 years" rather than "will be a viable alternative in 3 to 5 years."